# How to scale font sizes based on current DPI settings in VC++/MFC applications?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, dpi

How to scale font sizes based on current DPI settings in VC++/MFC applications ?

As of now when I change the DPI from 100% yo 150% the font sizes remain the same, although the icons will scale down based on the current dpi ..

Please suggest the best way for above problem.

Answer (score 4):

In Windows Vista and 7, the OS tries to hide the DPI from your program and does adjustments behind the scenes. If you want your program to react properly to DPI changes you must follow the guidelines from Microsoft titled [Creating a DPI-Aware Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms701681(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: That's interesting - does that mean that conversions from/to DLU's are out of the window completely now? How is one supposed to write an application that works on both XP and Vista/7?

Comment: @Roel, if you want an application that works *the same* between XP and Vista/7, just lookup the address of the SetProcessDPIAware function and call it if you find it.

Comment: @Roel, I think Microsoft did this because they found too many applications that didn't work well on XP when you change the DPI. This makes life easier for those that don't want to make the effort to do things right. I'm not sure specifically how DLUs are affected.

Comment: OK thank you - I think I don't understand the details enough to have an opinion on the merit of the new approach. From my cursory reading it seemed as if one would have to do the DLU juggle on WinXP and do it the way the article you linked to describes on Vista/7, effectively doubling the amount of work, but I guess I'm wrong on that assumption. Frankly, I'll be a happy man if I never have to investigate the details on this ;)

Answer (score 2):

By specifying the text and control sizes in DLU's. That happens by default though, so I assume you are generating dialogs dynamically or from a memory-based DLGTEMPLATE. If you, you're (pardon my French) screwed, because you'll have to muck about with converting DLU's to pixels, a very painful and tedious process. Read the following KB articles:

- http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;125681
- http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;145994

Answer (score 2):

Don't use DPI for font scaling.  Instead, use the settings the user has configured in the "Appearance" section of Control Panel.

You might also want to consider making the font size configurable for just your application.

Comment: making the font size configurable ...................How can be done in VC++ applicaton ?

Comment: @Ashish: Windows notepad.exe is a good example of this, choose Format menu -> Font.